# Creating URL query parameters from NSDictionary objects in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

With all the URL-handling objects lying around in the standard Cocoa libraries (NSURL, NSMutableURL, NSMutableURLRequest, etc), I know I must be overlooking an easy way to programmatically compose a GET request.

Currently I'm manually appending "?" followed by name value pairs joined by "&", but all of my name and value pairs need to be manually encoded so NSMutableURLRequest doesn't fail entirely when it tries to connect to the URL.

This feels like something I should be able to use a pre-baked API for.... is there anything out of the box to append an NSDictionary of query parameters to an NSURL? Is there another way I should approach this?

Comment: So many answers! So many votes on question and answers! And still its not marked answered. Woah!

Answer (score 134):

Introduced in iOS8 and OS X 10.10 is `NSURLQueryItem`, which can be used to build queries. From the docs on [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/index.html):

> An NSURLQueryItem object represents a single name/value pair for an item in the query portion of a URL. You use query items with the queryItems property of an NSURLComponents object.

To create one use the designated initializer `queryItemWithName:value:` and then add them to `NSURLComponents` to generate an `NSURL`. For example:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLQueryItem *search = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"q" value:@"ios"];
NSURLQueryItem *count = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"count" value:@"10"];
components.queryItems = @[ search, count ];
NSURL *url = components.URL; // http://stackoverflow.com?q=ios&count=10
```

Notice that the question mark and ampersand are automatically handled. Creating an `NSURL` from a dictionary of parameters is as simple as:

```
NSDictionary *queryDictionary = @{ @"q": @"ios", @"count": @"10" };
NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in queryDictionary) {
    [queryItems addObject:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:queryDictionary[key]]];
}
components.queryItems = queryItems;
```

I've also written a [blog post](http://masilotti.com/nsurlqueryitems) on how to build URLs with `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItems`.

Comment: what if the dictionary is nested?

Comment: @hariszaman if you're sending a nested dictionary via the URL you should probably think about sending it via the POST body instead.

Comment: just to note, value can only be of type NSString

Comment: Just want to stress a point here: value for an NSURLQueryItem can only be a string. It might result in a crash if not the case!

Answer (score 47):

You can create a category for `NSDictionary` to do this -- there isn't a standard way in the Cocoa library that I could find either.  The code that I use looks like this:

```
// file "NSDictionary+UrlEncoding.h"
#import <cocoa/cocoa.h>

@interface NSDictionary (UrlEncoding)

-(NSString*) urlEncodedString;

@end
```

with this implementation:

```
// file "NSDictionary+UrlEncoding.m"
#import "NSDictionary+UrlEncoding.h"

// helper function: get the string form of any object
static NSString *toString(id object) {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", object];
}

// helper function: get the url encoded string form of any object
static NSString *urlEncode(id object) {
  NSString *string = toString(object);
  return [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@implementation NSDictionary (UrlEncoding)

-(NSString*) urlEncodedString {
  NSMutableArray *parts = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (id key in self) {
    id value = [self objectForKey: key];
    NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@", urlEncode(key), urlEncode(value)];
    [parts addObject: part];
  }
  return [parts componentsJoinedByString: @"&"];
}

@end
```

I think the code's pretty straightforward, but I discuss it in some more detail at http://blog.ablepear.com/2008/12/urlencoding-category-for-nsdictionary.html.

Comment: I don't think this works. Specifically, you're using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, which does not escape ampersands, as well as other characters that must be escaped in query parameters as specified in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Consider looking at the [Google Toolbox For Mac escaping code](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.m) instead.

Comment: This works for proper escaping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187316/string-wont-url-encode-in-ios/9232341#9232341

Answer (score 30):

I wanted to use Chris's answer, but it wasn't written for *Automatic Reference Counting* (ARC) so I updated it.  I thought I'd paste my solution in case anyone else has this same issue.  **Note:** replace `self` with the instance or class name where appropriate.

```
+(NSString*)urlEscapeString:(NSString *)unencodedString 
{
    CFStringRef originalStringRef = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)unencodedString;
    NSString *s = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,originalStringRef, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFRelease(originalStringRef);
    return s;
}


+(NSString*)addQueryStringToUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableString *urlWithQuerystring = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    for (id key in dictionary) {
        NSString *keyString = [key description];
        NSString *valueString = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] description];

        if ([urlWithQuerystring rangeOfString:@"?"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [urlWithQuerystring appendFormat:@"?%@=%@", [self urlEscapeString:keyString], [self urlEscapeString:valueString]];
        } else {
            [urlWithQuerystring appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", [self urlEscapeString:keyString], [self urlEscapeString:valueString]];
        }
    }
    return urlWithQuerystring;
}
```

Comment: I like this code, only thing to add is for the encoding to be url safe for all key/values.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers work great if the values are strings, however if the values are dictionaries or arrays then this code will handle that.

*Its important to note that there is no standard way of passing an array/dictionary via the query string but PHP handles this output just fine*

```
-(NSString *)serializeParams:(NSDictionary *)params {
    /*

     Convert an NSDictionary to a query string

     */

    NSMutableArray* pairs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString* key in [params keyEnumerator]) {
        id value = [params objectForKey:key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            for (NSString *subKey in value) {
                NSString* escaped_value = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                              (CFStringRef)[value objectForKey:subKey],
                                                                                              NULL,
                                                                                              (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
                [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]=%@", key, subKey, escaped_value]];
            }
        } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (NSString *subValue in value) {
                NSString* escaped_value = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                              (CFStringRef)subValue,
                                                                                              NULL,
                                                                                              (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
                [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]=%@", key, escaped_value]];
            }
        } else {
            NSString* escaped_value = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                          (CFStringRef)[params objectForKey:key],
                                                                                          NULL,
                                                                                          (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                          kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
            [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, escaped_value]];
            [escaped_value release];
        }
    }
    return [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
}
```

**Examples**

```
[foo] => bar
[translations] => 
        {
            [one] => uno
            [two] => dos
            [three] => tres
        }
```

**foo=bar&translations[one]=uno&translations[two]=dos&translations[three]=tres**

```
[foo] => bar
[translations] => 
        {
            uno
            dos
            tres
        }
```

**foo=bar&translations[]=uno&translations[]=dos&translations[]=tres**

Comment: For the final 'else' case, I added a call to description so that it will provide strings for NSNumbers rather than barfing on a call to length: '(CFStringRef)[[params objectForKey:key] **description**]'    Thanks!

Comment: great answer. However you should replace `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` calls with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]`

Answer (score 8):

I refactored and converted to ARC answer by AlBeebe

```
- (NSString *)serializeParams:(NSDictionary *)params {
    NSMutableArray *pairs = NSMutableArray.array;
    for (NSString *key in params.keyEnumerator) {
        id value = params[key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            for (NSString *subKey in value)
                [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]=%@", key, subKey, [self escapeValueForURLParameter:[value objectForKey:subKey]]]];

        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            for (NSString *subValue in value)
            [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]=%@", key, [self escapeValueForURLParameter:subValue]]];

        else
            [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [self escapeValueForURLParameter:value]]];

}
return [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
```

}

```
- (NSString *)escapeValueForURLParameter:(NSString *)valueToEscape {
     return (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) valueToEscape,
             NULL, (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, but I changed the last line in order to include a ? before the first param:
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@",[pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]];`

Comment: i think you should replace `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` calls `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharac‌​terSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]`

Answer (score 6):

If you are already using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (as was the case with me), you can use it's class `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` to create the required `NSURLRequest`.

`[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"YOUR_URL" parameters:@{PARAMS} error:nil];`

In case you only require the URL for your work, use `NSURLRequest.URL`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example in **Swift** (iOS8+):

```
private let kSNStockInfoFetchRequestPath: String = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/json"

private func SNStockInfoFetchRequestURL(symbol:String) -> NSURL? {
  if let components = NSURLComponents(string:kSNStockInfoFetchRequestPath) {
    components.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name:"symbol", value:symbol)]
    return components.URL
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Pretty neat, but `queryItems` are available from iOS8.0.

Comment: Thanks, added a comment to clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

I took Joel's recommendation of using `URLQueryItems` and turned into a Swift Extension (Swift 3)

```
extension URL
{
    /// Creates an NSURL with url-encoded parameters.
    init?(string : String, parameters : [String : String])
    {
        guard var components = URLComponents(string: string) else { return nil }

        components.queryItems = parameters.map { return URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1) }

        guard let url = components.url else { return nil }

        // Kinda redundant, but we need to call init.
        self.init(string: url.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

(The `self.init` method is kinda cheesy, but there was no `NSURL` init with components)

Can be used as

```
URL(string: "http://www.google.com/", parameters: ["q" : "search me"])
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got another solution:

http://splinter.com.au/build-a-url-query-string-in-obj-c-from-a-dict

```
+(NSString*)urlEscape:(NSString *)unencodedString {
    NSString *s = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
        (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
        NULL,
        (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [s autorelease]; // Due to the 'create rule' we own the above and must autorelease it
}

// Put a query string onto the end of a url
+(NSString*)addQueryStringToUrl:(NSString *)url params:(NSDictionary *)params {
    NSMutableString *urlWithQuerystring = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:url] autorelease];
    // Convert the params into a query string
    if (params) {
        for(id key in params) {
            NSString *sKey = [key description];
            NSString *sVal = [[params objectForKey:key] description];
            // Do we need to add ?k=v or &k=v ?
            if ([urlWithQuerystring rangeOfString:@"?"].location==NSNotFound) {
                [urlWithQuerystring appendFormat:@"?%@=%@", [Http urlEscape:sKey], [Http urlEscape:sVal]];
            } else {
                [urlWithQuerystring appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", [Http urlEscape:sKey], [Http urlEscape:sVal]];
            }
        }
    }
    return urlWithQuerystring;
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"username":@"jim", @"password":@"abc123"};

NSString *urlWithQuerystring = [self addQueryStringToUrl:@"https://myapp.com/login" params:params];
```

Comment: Please post relevant code in your answer, that link may not be around forever.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString*)encodeDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{
    NSMutableString *bodyData = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *key in dictionary.allKeys) {
        i++;
        [bodyData appendFormat:@"%@=",key];
        NSString *value = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
        NSString *newString = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
        [bodyData appendString:newString];
        if (i < dictionary.allKeys.count) {
            [bodyData appendString:@"&"];
        }
    }
    return bodyData;
}
```

Comment: This does not properly encode special characters in names or values (other than space).

Comment: I don't believe space should be replaced by + but rather by %20 and this is the only character changed

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, if you use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) there's a function in `RKURLEncodedSerialization` called `RKURLEncodedStringFromDictionaryWithEncoding` that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of converting NSDictionary to url query string in Objective-c

Ex: first_name=Steve&middle_name=Gates&last_name=Jobs&address=Palo Alto, California

```
    NSDictionary *sampleDictionary = @{@"first_name"         : @"Steve",
                                     @"middle_name"          : @"Gates",
                                     @"last_name"            : @"Jobs",
                                     @"address"              : @"Palo Alto, California"};

    NSMutableString *resultString = [NSMutableString string];
            for (NSString* key in [sampleDictionary allKeys]){
                if ([resultString length]>0)
                    [resultString appendString:@"&"];
                [resultString appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [sampleDictionary objectForKey:key]];
            }
NSLog(@"QueryString: %@", resultString);
```

Hope will help :)

Comment: This is incorrect because it does not escape characters such as "&" if they'd appear in the dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using [AFNetwork](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), you can use their built in serializer to to produce an encoded URL;

```
NSString *baseURL = @"https://api.app.com/parse";
NSDictionary *mutableParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"true",@"option1", data, @"option2", token, @"token", @"3.0", @"app", nil];
NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:baseURL parameters:mutableParameters error:nil];
NSString *urlPath = request.URL.absoluteString;
NSLog(@"%@", urlPath); // https://api.app.com/parse?option1=true&option2=datavalue&token=200%3ATEST%3AENCODE ....
```

*Note; this is an extension to an above answer. The edit queue is full so cannot be added to the existing answer.*