# Encoding string arguments for URLs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I created a method to build URLs for me.

```
- (NSString *)urlFor:(NSString *)path arguments:(NSDictionary *)args
{
    NSString *format = @"http://api.example.com/%@?version=2.0.1";
    NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:format, path];

    if ([args isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (NSString *key in args) {
            [url appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, [args objectForKey:key]]];
        }
    }

    return url;
}
```

When I try to build something like below, the URLs aren't encoded, of course.

```
NSDictionary *args = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"http://other.com", @"url",
                            @"ABCDEF", @"apiKey", nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [self urlFor:@"articles" arguments:args]);`
```

The returned value is **http://api.example.com/articles?version=2.0.1&url=http://other.com&apiKey=ABCDEF** when it should be **http://api.example.com/articles?version=2.0.1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fother.com&apiKey=ABCDEF**.

I need to encode both key and value. I searched for something and found **CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes** and **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding** but none of the tests I made worked.

How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry! My code broke the syntax highlighting and I can't fix it! Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, slashes should be interpreted properly when they're in the query part of a URL. Did you test to see if it still works without encoded slashses? Otherwise, do something like:

```
if ([args isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (NSString *key in [args allKeys]) {
            NSString *value = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[args objectForKey:key], NULL, CFSTR("/?&:=#"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
            [url appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, value]];
            [value release];
        }
}

return url;
```

Note the value of the 4th argument to CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes.

Comment: One question: the 4th argument can accept any character that need to be encoded?

Comment: Yes. From the documentation:

legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped
Legal characters to be escaped. Pass NULL to specify that no legal characters be replaced.

There are only a few characters that would otherwise not be escaped, but I went the safe route because I was too lazy to look up which ones those were (though it'd probably be a good idea).

Comment: This leaks memory.  `value` is an owned object that is discarded without being released.

Comment: You're right; I'll edit it. Can't believe I blitzed that out…

Comment: This is actually bad code (as of now). I think the memory stuff is a bit messed up. Check out this question for better/updated code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec

Comment: It's not bad; it's just old and pre-ARC.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Google Toolbox for Mac's GTMNSString+URLArguments](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.h); it's designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I'll check GTM. Apparently this library is a good one because every question on SO mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend our [KSFileUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities) set of classes. Your example would then be:

```
- (NSString *)urlFor:(NSString *)path arguments:(NSDictionary *)args
{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:args];
    [parameters setObject:@"2.0.1" forKey:@"version"];

    NSURL *result = [NSURL ks_URLWithScheme:@"http"
                                       host:@"api.example.com"
                                       path:path
                            queryParameters:parameters;

    return [result absoluteString];
}
```