# ios - how do I concatinate strings to create a url?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsstring

I am trying to make a url by first collecting the parameters, and then in one statement creating the actual url.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.some_login_url.com?email=%@&password=%@";

NSString *email = self.email.text;
NSString *password = self.password.text;

NSString *url_to_send = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlString , email , password];
```

So what I wanted to do was replace the @ symbols with the values in the variables, but instead the second variable just got appended to the end of the string.

How would I change the last line so I could put the right parameters in their correct spots?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
NSString *url_to_send = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString , email , password];
```

But you might want to look for ways to construct a URL that do proper escaping of arguments, etc. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250212/encoding-string-arguments-for-urls).

Comment: do you mean that line where they have the             NSString *value = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[args objectForKey:key], NULL, CFSTR("/?&:=#"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];

Comment: Yes, or either of the other two answers which suggest libraries that do this for you (and handle other issues like adding the ? and & characters as needed, etc.)

Comment: if I am just sending the url, is handling the & and the ? characters that important? In the example in this comment, its a bit crypitic for me to read still....which is the actual variable that is used? Any chance you could post how mine should look like? THanks!

Comment: btw I am also sending a password field. I was wondering if there is something else other than a secure connection that needs to be done for that field.

Comment: You might want to search around or post another question about the security issue, but yes, you should at least be using HTTPS if you're sending a clear-text password. As for the & and ? characters, if you add escaping code like you posted above, that'll be fine. I just meant that those libraries will add them in for you between parameters as needed instead of having to hard-code them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The urlString *is* your format, so you want:

```
NSString *url_to_send = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString , email , password];
```