# How to add GET parameters to an ASIHttpRequest?

Tags: iphone, get, asihttprequest

How can I add GET parameters to an ASIHttpRequest?

I want to go from `http://mysite.com/server` to `http://mysite.com/server?a=1&b=2` programmatically.

I have all my parameters as key-value pairs in an NSDictionary object.

Thanks

Comment: This has been discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string format like

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"a",@"2",@"b", nil];

NSMutableString *prams = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (id keys in dict) {
    [prams appendFormat:@"%@=%@&",keys,[dict objectForKey:keys]];
}
NSString *removeLastChar = [prams substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [prams length]-1)];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/server?%@",removeLastChar];

NSLog(@"urlString %@",urlString);
```

Comment: It does not escape special characters.