# How would i create a GET method to a webserver with AFNetwork

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, afnetworking

I was wondering how i would get AFNetworking code to visit a link on my web server(PHP Script) and get the response data, and put it into a string?

Could anyone post an example of this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

here is the required code to get response from server using AFNETWorking.Just add AFNetworking Library and the Required frameWorks.After that use the below code.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=harry&country=us&entity=movie"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"JSON");

            self.movies = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
            [self.tbleView reloadData];

           } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        }];
```

self.movies is name of mutable Array you can use any name instead of this.

Also you can check here

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

AFHTTPRequests get passed default NSURLRequest objects. stock ones - no modification for AFNetwork

to build THAT see
[How to add GET parameters to an ASIHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159663/how-to-add-get-parameters-to-an-asihttprequest)