# Setting http headers on AFNetworking 1X JSON Request

Tags: ios, json, http-headers, afnetworking

I am passing parameters to a REST web service and it keeps saying:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format 
not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

I create a NSDictionary like this with all my parameters:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *webServiceParameters;
    webServiceParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [webServiceParameters setObject:mytextbox.text forKey:@"value1"];
```

Then I pass it into the request:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webServiceURL];
        AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
               NSURLRequest *myRequest = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:webServiceParameters];
        client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

        NSLog(@"%@", myRequest);

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
    operation =  [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest

                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSDictionary *JSON)
                  {


                  }



                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSArray *JSON)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
                  }
                  ];

    [operation start];
```

My assumption is that the :

```
client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
```

would turn the parameters into a JSON request but its not changing the header file. I couldnt figure out a way to change the header file on this. All the documentation on AFNetworking is now in 2.0 and I still have to use 1.X.. How can I pass a value in the header to tell it that its application/json and will that parameterEncoding actually pass it as JSON?

I have tried:  `[myRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@""];` but the compiler throws this error:

```
No visible interface for NSUrlRequest declares the selector setValue: for HTTPHeaderField
```

Comment: this might help [way to attach NSDictonary][1]


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299362/is-there-any-way-to-attach-a-nsdictionary-of-parameters-to-an-nsurlrequest-inste