# Unsupported URL when sending Json value as argument in GET method

Tags: ios, json, xcode6

```
Code:
     arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chennai", nil];
            arrKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"loc", nil];
            dicValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrValues forKeys:arrKeys];
             NSString *strMethodName = @"agentuserlist";

            strUrlName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?filters=%@",appDelegate.strURL, strMethodName, dicValue];
            //strUrlName = [strUrlName stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrlName] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:250.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

        [request setValue:@"zyt45HuJ70oPpWl7" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *received = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error);

        NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:received encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"response :%@", strResponse);
```

I try to send json argument through get method.It gives error as `"unsupported url(-1002)"`.

The URL is working fine when I checked with Postman. I am unable to find out the problem.

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you write out the content of `request.absoluteString`? Do you get the error when creating the `NSURL` instance or when trying to send the request?

Comment: i am getting response as Unsupported URL

Comment: do u want entire URL?

Comment: just log your strUrlName, I guess its not correct!

Comment: The building of the URL like this is simply incorrect. You can't just `stringWithFormat` a dictionary into a URL (even if you percent escaped it) and expect it to work. You must first confirm what the web service requires, and only then can you go about building a request. I suspect that something like Romain's answer is likely, but don't know where this `filters=` falls into the mix (I presume you picked that up from somewhere in the documentation). But it's silly for us to try to tell you how to fix this without clear guidance on what the web service expects.

Comment: (By the way, when you get this current problem behind you, you really should retire the use of synchronous requests.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in how you encode your `NSDictionary` in the `NSURL`.

You probably want your URL to look like this: `http://my domain.com/agentuserlist?loc=Chennai`. But the raw encoding of the `NSDictionary` inside the `NSURL` doesn't produce this result.

You can follow the accepted answer
from this question to get an idea of how to transform an `NSDictionary` into a regular list of URL parameters (with proper encoding of dictionary values: don't forget the `stringByAddingPercentEscapeUsingEncoding` part): [Creating URL query parameters from NSDictionary objects in ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec)