# Recursive URL parameters construction

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, nsurl

I have a `NSDictionary` parameters written like this :

```
{
  "aKey" : [
    {
      "associated_values" : [
        42,
        43,
      ],
      "internal_id" : 3
    }
  ],
  "another_Key" : false
}
```

Is there a simple way to construct a URL with is formatted this way for a `GET` method :

```
https://www.url.com/another_key=false?aKey[0][internal_id]=3&aKey[0][associated_values][0]=42&aKey[0][associated_values][1]=43
```

We can imagine that `associated_values` can also contains subjson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating URL query parameters from NSDictionary objects in ObjectiveC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec)

Comment: Yes I already read it but it's not assuming data can be recursive and each subvalues are NSString